# Sublime. Подсказки autocomplete пропадают слишком быстро. Как увеличить время отображения?

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Подсказки autocomplete (выпадающий список) пропадают слишком быстро. 
Как увеличить время отображения?

В настройках нашел только опцию

```
"auto_complete_delay": 50,
```

Но это задержка *перед* появлением выпадающего списка, но не длительность его отображения.
Есть еще какие-то способы?

Comment: Использую Sublime Text 3. Подсказки autocomplete вообще не пропадают пока есть совпадения с вариантами. Конкретизируйте пожалуйста почему они у Вас пропадают и в чём именно проблема.

Comment: Ну и перенеси эти настройки в пользовательские настройки и измени `"auto_complete_delay": 50` на побольше, сколько тебе хочется....

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с тойже проблеммой.

Исходные данные:

1. У меня установлены плагины autocomplete и auto-safe. В Настройках auto-safe включено автоматическое сохранение файлов:

   ```
    {
     "auto_save_on_modified": **true**,
     "auto_save_delay_in_seconds": 1,
     "auto_save_all_files": true,
     "auto_save_current_file": "",
     "auto_save_backup": false,
     "auto_save_backup_suffix": "autosave"
   }
   ```
2. Подсказки autocomplete (выпадающий список) пропадают слишком быстро.

Как я это решил:
Отключил автоматическое сохранение файлов:

```
{
  "auto_save_on_modified": **false**,
  "auto_save_delay_in_seconds": 1,
  "auto_save_all_files": true,
  "auto_save_current_file": "",
  "auto_save_backup": false,
  "auto_save_backup_suffix": "autosave"
}
```

после этого действия autocomplete заработал в штатном режиме.

---

Auto-safe не сохраняет автоматически изменения, но работает autocomplete, теперь думаю как сделать так чтобы работаи оба плагина одновременно.
Если у кого есть другие решения проблеммы просьба сообщить.